# Blur google map v2 after zooming in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm developing a program in android with googlemapsv2 api.

There is a small problem - At first, when the map is first initialized, it is looking great. But after i am trying to zoom and see roads, the map becomes blur and not clear.

Is there any attribute that I should put in order that the zoom will work fine?
In google maps application it works just fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Because of low connection speed, map might be blurry. When you Zoom in, new frames are loaded, and that requires more data, which on low speed connection will cause blurry map at first.

Comment: @Dhaval No, this is not the problem. My connection speed is more than great. And also, as I said, it does not happen in the google maps application.

Comment: Do you have solution? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

NEW: I did implement the new map renderer from SDK 18+  and improved my maps, now 5x faster & smoother. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer

Add this to your build.Gradle
**implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0"**

In your app (MainActivity)

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.Renderer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback;

class MapRendererOptInApplication extends Application implements **OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback** {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    **MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext(), Renderer.LATEST, this);**
  }

  @Override
  public void onMapsSdkInitialized(MapsInitializer.Renderer renderer) {
    switch (renderer) {
      case LATEST:
        Log.d("MapsDemo", "The latest version of the renderer is used.");
        break;
      case LEGACY:
        Log.d("MapsDemo", "The legacy version of the renderer is used.");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to start the camera in the Ui Thread. This improves the situation for me.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                            new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()))
                                    .tilt(70)
                                    .zoom(zoom)
                                    .build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
            });
```